# Non-unital ring $(2\mathbb{Z})[X]$ is not Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian, rngs

> Let $R = 2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $R[x]$ is not a noetherian ring.

I do not understand why this is so, because Hilbert's basis theorem says: If R Noetherian ring, then R[X] a is Noetherian ring (from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_basis_theorem)).

I suppose that $2\mathbb{Z}$ is principal ideal ring:
Let (2), (4), (6), ... are the ideals, therefore all elements are generated by one ideal, so $2\mathbb{Z}$ is principal ideal ring. And we conclude that $2\mathbb{Z}$
is a noetherian ring. Why can't use Hilbert's basis theorem for $R[x]$?

Comment: Does the definition of "ring" in the wikipedia article require the existence of $1$? And are you certain that $R[x]$ isn't Noetherian?

Comment: I think is because $2\mathbb{Z}$ has not unity.

Comment: @Arthur I believe Hilbert's theorem holds for non unity rings

Comment: @Arthur I think, that by definition of Noetherian ring, Hilbert's theorem should be require the existence of 1 (or I'm wrong?).

Comment: I don’t know if the Hilbert basis theorem works in rings without identity or not, but it still seems like $R[x]$ is noetherian. A bigger question is why $R[x]$ looks like when $R$ doesn’t have identity. Where do you see the claim?

Comment: @rschwieb in my homework =). Actually, this task confuses me, so I asked this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Hilbert basis theorem only applies to unital rings (this is often not stated explicitly since unital is often included in the definition of "ring").  Since $2\mathbb{Z}$ is not unital, the Hilbert basis theorem does not apply in this case.

An example of a non-finitely generated ideal in $2\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is the entire ring $2\mathbb{Z}[x]$ itself.  (Note that for this to be true, $2\mathbb{Z}[x]$ must be defined as the set of polynomials all of whose coefficients are in $2\mathbb{Z}$, rather than the ring obtained from $2\mathbb{Z}$ by freely adjoining a central element $x$.  This distinction does not make a difference for unital rings.)

Comment: dear Eric, just to make sure, by $2\mathbb{Z}$ with a freely adjoined central element $x$ do you mean for example the subring $2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\langle x\rangle$ of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? (as a side question, do you know what the usual convention is, if there is any, for defining polynomial rings over non-unital rings?) (+1)

Comment: Actually, I mean the subring $2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \langle x\rangle$ of $A[x]$ where $A$ is the ring obtained by freely adjoining a unit to $2\mathbb{Z}$.  (So, in this ring, $x+x$ is *not* the same as $2x$ where $2$ refers to the element of $2\mathbb{Z}$.)  This is only natural because $2\mathbb{Z}$ does not "know" intrinsically that it is a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$.  I don't know what the usual convention is, but freely adjoining a central element seems like it would be a much more useful notion.

Comment: ah, that makes sense completely, thank you. strange stuff! I find non-unital rings really bizarre, but maybe it's just because I'm not used to them